# Create Outlook calendar appointment with attachment through Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I want to add attachments when creating an appointment in a shared Outlook calendar.

I create appointments with this code.

```vb
Option Explicit
Public Sub CreateOutlookAppointments()
   Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    On Error GoTo Err_Execute
     
    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim olAppt As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim blnCreated As Boolean
    Dim olNs As Outlook.Namespace
    Dim CalFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim myRecipient As Outlook.Recipient
    
    Dim i As Long
     
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = Outlook.Application
     
    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        Set olApp = Outlook.Application
         blnCreated = True
        Err.Clear
    Else
        blnCreated = False
    End If
     
    On Error GoTo 0
     
    Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set myRecipient = olNs.CreateRecipient("warehouse")
 
    myRecipient.Resolve
 
    If myRecipient.Resolved Then
        Dim CalendarFolder As Outlook.Folder
        Set CalFolder = olNs.GetSharedDefaultFolder(myRecipient, olFolderCalendar)
    End If
    
    i = 2
    Do Until Trim(Cells(i, 1).Value) = ""
     
        Set olAppt = CalFolder.Items.Add(olAppointmentItem)
    
        With olAppt
            'Define calendar item properties
            .Start = Cells(i, 5) + Cells(i, 6)
            .End = Cells(i, 7) + Cells(i, 8)
            .Subject = Cells(i, 1)
            .Location = Cells(i, 2)
            .Body = Cells(i, 3)
            .BusyStatus = olBusy
            .ReminderMinutesBeforeStart = Cells(i, 9)
            .ReminderSet = True
            .Categories = Cells(i, 4)
            .Save
            ' For meetings or Group Calendars
            ' .Send
        End With
                 
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    Set olAppt = Nothing
    Set olApp = Nothing
     
    Exit Sub
     
Err_Execute:
    MsgBox "An error occurred - Exporting items to Calendar."
     
End Sub
```

I am trying to add attachments from a file path in the cells of the sheet just like the appointments are being created by populated cells.

| Subject | Location | Body | Category | Start | start time | End | end time | reminder | Attachments |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Test |  |  | Important | 30/12/23 | 01:00 | 30/12/23 | 03:00 | 15 | X:\FolderPath |

Comment: `olAppt.Attachments.Add FileNameAndPath`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you, with persistence I found my Answer
this was the addition to my code i needed as index rows and file paths was found in column 10 this code in the 'define calendar item properties helped attach items to the calendar

```
'Add attachment to the Calendar item
Dim attachmentPath As String
attachmentPath = Cells(i, 10)
    .Attachments.Add attachmentPath
```